# How can I define and initialize a numpy matrix of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
M = np.zeros((N,L))
```

The above statement gives a ***N x L*** matrix initially filled with 0. I need a similar statement to create a ***N x L*** matrix filled with `(0,0)` tuples. How can I create it?

Comment: Create a 3D array instead : `M = np.zeros((N,L,2))`?

Comment: Why not just use a 3D array?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231190/python-numpy-tuples-as-elements-of-an-array) might help

Answer (score 1):

How about this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17960617/2864250):

```
N = 3
L = 3
M = np.zeros((N,L))
res =  np.array(list(zip(M.ravel(),M.ravel())), dtype=('i4,i4')).reshape(M.shape)

# returns
array([[(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)],
       [(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)],
       [(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]], dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```